# Is the Pod Resources API disabled on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

### Problem Summary:

We're using [DCGM Exporter](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:k8s:dcgm-exporter) to collect metrics about GPU workloads. When deployed on GKE, the exporter does not return GPU information about other pods or containers (when it's expected to return that information).

This exporter runs a replica on every node and queries the [Pod Resource API](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/16/third-party-device-metrics-reaches-ga/) exposed by the kubelet to get the needed data. It seems that on GKE, this API is disabled or configured differently compared to other kubernetes distributions.

### Problem Demonstration:

Our test scenario consists of deploying a one-node cluster with `dcgm-exporter` running on it along with a one-replica deployment (called `cuda-test` in this demo) that uses GPU resources.

We query the exporter through its `/metrics` endpoint, and the results are as follows.

When running on rancher k3s `v1.20.4+k3s1`, the `container` and `pod` labels contain a value:

```python
dcgm_sm_clock{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-a2bf9768-0411-f0bb-791c-67d5fec65e2f",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-xzpt9",container="cuda-test-main",namespace="default",pod="cuda-test-687bddf45c-qjl6x"} 1860
dcgm_memory_clock{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-a2bf9768-0411-f0bb-791c-67d5fec65e2f",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-xzpt9",container="cuda-test-main",namespace="default",pod="cuda-test-687bddf45c-qjl6x"} 9501
dcgm_gpu_temp{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-a2bf9768-0411-f0bb-791c-67d5fec65e2f",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-xzpt9",container="cuda-test-main",namespace="default",pod="cuda-test-687bddf45c-qjl6x"} 41
```

But when running on GKE `v1.19.8-gke.1600`, the `container` and `pod` labels both have empty values:

```python
dcgm_sm_clock{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-bcb71627-8b00-b4aa-70d7-ce39fd6cbb01",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-ln6x4",container="",namespace="",pod=""} 585
dcgm_memory_clock{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-bcb71627-8b00-b4aa-70d7-ce39fd6cbb01",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-ln6x4",container="",namespace="",pod=""} 5000
dcgm_gpu_temp{gpu="0",UUID="GPU-bcb71627-8b00-b4aa-70d7-ce39fd6cbb01",device="nvidia0",Hostname="dcgm-exporter-ln6x4",container="",namespace="",pod=""} 76
```

I haven't been able to find any information about whether GKE disables this API (which was introduced in k8s `1.13`) or restricts certain values from being exposed. I'd like to learn more about the matter and find a solution in order for the exporter to access and collect the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding the argument `--kubernetes-gpu-id-type device-name` to the `dcgm-exporter` does it.

On GKE, apparently, the pod resource API does not return a value for the GPU's `uid` (which is the default value for the argument), and that's why the information about the pods and containers was getting skipped.